# Creating Google Analytics Dashboard for site users?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

We currently own a crowdfunding platform and we utilize Google Analytics to help project creators see how their projects are performing. We want to make it easier for them to manage it by using the Google Embed API to create a Google Analytics Dashboard within the platform for each user. The user would be able to go into their account dashboard and see their Google analytics without going to google.

Is this possible? If so, could you direct me to the right location? Currently, it would seem you need to supply a client ID that needs to have the site verified at the TXT record level. That's impossible for clients to access, let alone the amount of steps they would be required to complete.

The other option I see is to get the Client ID for a particular tracker but I have read that this doesn't provide a way to access the whole history of their analytics.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly by now you might simply create a nicely formatted report (including nice graphics etc) in [Google Data Studio](https://www.google.com/analytics/data-studio/) and click "share".

If you insist on having this inside your application you could create a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) and have an application on your server authenticate against Google Analytics and let if fetch the data. For visualisation you could use Google Charts, which I think is what the embed API is using so you should get a similar look.

Comment: Thank you for the information. 

Yeah, we'd like to keep it within the platform to help users navigate more and to allow them a "All-in-one" Analytics dashboard that will show Googles as well as other analytics they choose. 

Could the service account display analytics for a single page? We don't want users being able to see other users analytics.

Comment: Service account just means that a server application authenticates against GA without the need for an interactive login (you need to add the service account user to the GA account in question, though). You would then execute queries against the account just like you would in the Embed API, and set any filters you want to use in the query to show only the data a particular user is supposed to see.

Comment: I just noticed that he documentation for the embed API actually has a tutorial for using a service account with the embed API: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/, so you will be still able to use that. Just retrieve the auth token from the server application, and the rest just works as before.